# Sugarcrm 6.1.2 Pro External Accounts tab does not appear on edit user view

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have SugarCrm 6.1.2 Pro version installed and working. Now I wanted to integrate google docs with my user accounts. But for that I need to create an account using the external accounts tab on edit user view.

When i go on the edit user view I am not able to see the external accounts tab after the advanced tab but there is a download tab which shows some plugins to download for word and office.

Can anyone help me why external accounts tab is not visible. I googled a lot but am not able to find any thing specific to it.

Regards,
Vishan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think External Accounts were available in 6.1, they were introduced in 6.2. It's hard to tell, though, because these are both old, unsupported versions and I can't dig up any release notes for 6.2 to announce this.

Full documentation for SugarCRM 6.1.x is available here: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/08_Unsupported_Versions/Sugar_6.1/

And for 6.2.x: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/08_Unsupported_Versions/Sugar_6.2/